# what exactly does system.totalMemory test in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory-management

before somebody screaming RTFM, let me clarify.

does system.totalMemory test the memory used in movie which invokes it, or used by all movies running on the browser/system?

I want to initiate garbage collaction for my app when it reaches a certain limit and i dont want the process to be initialized by the user watching funny cats youtube video.

Answer (score 1):

edit: misread a part

after some testing, it gives the amount of bytes currently in use byt the flash player that is calling the system.totalMemory

Comment: nope.. i just tested it as well. it picked up youtube memory in a separate tab as well

Comment: at first i thought that aswell, but than i testet with newgrounds in another tab and it didnt change the value, maby it needs a bit more testing.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this site Adobe is telling us that System.totalMemory reports a cumulative memory usage of all Flash Player instances on the machine:
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Why_is_System_totalMemory_reported_by_the_API_call-12027.html